# python runs but stop working and nothing happens

Tags: python, class, openpyxl, execution

I am trying to run the code, but it stops working when runs to print('continue') and then nothing happens at all. I have tried to install new python version and also other programs with classes work.
Please, give me some hint why this doesn't run properly.

```
import os
import os.path
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

os.chdir('/Users/ns.blinnikova/Desktop')

class SearchTeachers:

def __init__(self, sheetFileName, sheetGoogleName):
    self.sheetWithTeachers = load_workbook(sheetFileName)['Лист1'] 
    self.sheet_to_work = load_workbook(sheetGoogleName)['Data']  
    self.end_row = self.sheet_to_work.max_row
    self.n = 1


def createFile(self, filenumber): 
    self.filenumber = filenumber
    newFile = 'phd' + str(self.filenumber) + '.csv'
    self.FillFile = open(newFile, 'w')                 
    self.FillFile.write("username;password;course1;type1")
    self.FillFile.write('\n') 
    print("file is done" + newFile)
    return self.FillFile

filenum = 1
print('continue')
wobject = SearchTeachers('somefile.xlsx', 'another file.xlsx')
print(wobject)
fillingFile = wobject.createFile(filenum)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I always use this way to catch a non-obvious error, but this time the problem was with the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the Serbian for `Sheet1` (`Лист1`) suppose to be there?
2. Do the two XLSX files exist on the desktop (as chdir suggests)?

Consider first trying the `load_workbook` functions instead of creating wobject -- just as a sanity check.

Comment: thank a lot, the problem was with the file itself, somehow, the formating style in the excel sheet was somehow stopping the code execution, so I changed the formating style and it worked. But still it seems to me very confusing why it was so.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. There should have been a mechanism to capture this type issue. Please consider having a word with the owners of the library.